# Using ''User Notifications" Graph API for Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Since Graph API v2.3, the notification request have been deprecated. I am new to using the API's and I was wondering how to use the POST edge request found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/notifications/

More specifically, to retrieve the unread notification's for a user.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
function getInfo() {
  FB.api("/me/notifications", function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
}
```

Comment: I think, in much of the problem may lies in the lack of knowledge about the whole conceptions of the REST. Try to read 2-3 different tutorials how the REST things works (take your time, and get better perspective of it) and try to look again on this problem. TIP: to reach some endpoints you will have to be logged into the service (read as well how the FB authentication works). And good luck!

Comment: This isn’t possible any more. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_deprecations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That endpoint is for sending notifications only, you can´t get the unread notifications anymore. And you need to use an App Token with an App Scoped ID for that call. You should not use an App Token client side, so sending notifications should always be done server side.

More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/appnotifications

Comment: To be more precise, you can read notifications, but only for pages.

Comment: @analytik correct, but the thread is about user notifications specifically :)